# How to open a PowerPoint slide using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```vb
Sub Day1()

Dim objPPT As Object

Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set PowerPoint.Slide = 5
objPPT.Visible = True

objPPT.Presentations.Open "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Macro Test\Day 1.pptx"

End Sub
```

I want this to open the fifth slide on my PowerPoint presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is almost right. Just needed to use the right object, and select the slide.

```
Dim objPPT As Object
Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

objPPT.Visible = True

objPPT.Presentations.Open("your file")

objPPT.Slides(5).Select
```

Comment: Or use ActiveWindow.View.GoToSlide(5)